# Django REST Framework: Handling models that are indirectly related via deep nesting

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have several models in Django:

- `Device`
- `Region`
- `Installation`: has a `Device` and `Region`:

  ```
  region = models.ForeignKey(Region, related_name='installations')
  device = models.ForeignKey(Device, related_name='installations')
  ```
- `Dashboard`: has several `Region`s:

  ```
  regions = models.ManyToManyField(Region, related_name='dashboards')
  ```

If I am interested in the connection between instances of `Device` and `Dashboard`, what are the best practices for these types of models in Django? For example, here is how I serialize a `Dashboard` if I want to see its related `Device`s:

```
class DeviceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Device
        fields = ['uuid', 'device_type']

class DashboardSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    devices = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_devices(self, obj):
        flat_devices = []
        for region in obj.regions.all():
            for installation in region.installations.all():
                flat_devices.append(installation.device)
        return DeviceSerializer(flat_devices, many=True).data

    class Meta:
        model = Dashboard
        fields = ['uuid', 'devices']
```

Does Django offer a better way of doing this?

What about the other way around, i.e. a `Device` serializer that includes a list of the `Dashboard`s it appears on?

Answer (score 0):

Use filtering with relation lookups:

```
device = Device.objects.get(...)  # just picturing it's a single object
Dashboard.objects.filter(regions__installations__device=device)
```

You can also change your existing `for loops` into one `filter` method:

```
dashboard = Dashboard.objects.get(...)  # just picturing it's a single object
devices = Device.objects.filter(installations__region__dashboards=dashboard)
```